# Low resolution icons in task-switcher in kde

Tags: icons, kde, display-resolution, plasma

I am using kde neon 5.8.4 user edition. When I press switch windows ALT+TAB, the icons that appear are **distorted** most of times.

1. Below is my settings for window switching.
   [image]

   2. Problem.
      [image]
   3. At first, I thought this was due to the applications shipped with low-resolution icons, but this is false. As when using icon-manager taskbar, I hover over the same application icons and they are high-resolution with no distortion at all.
      [image]

[image]

How do I fix this? Is this a bug?

Comment: Here is some deeper information on this: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=351055 Long story short: It is stated that the responsive devs of each app would have to include higher resolution icons for their windows. (Last comment as of Nov. 2016)

Comment: tha same problem on f26 kde plasma spin, framework 5.36.0

Answer (score 3):

By default, KDE uses the icon supplied by the running application. This can sometimes be useful, for example if the application wants to show a different icon for different windows, or if it wants to make the icon dynamic.

For example, the first application in the task switcher, The GIMP, shows the image being edited:

[image]

However for many apps this is not useful, and the low-res icons can be annoying.

You can override the default behaviour for a specific application, by asking the window manager to use a specific desktop file.  You do this in the `Special Application Settings`

[image]

Often you can simply point to the app's own desktop file, at `/usr/share/applications/APP_NAME.desktop`

[image]

If you cannot find this on the title bar, then you can instead open KDE's `System Settings` and search for `Window Rules` there.

[image]

If the application has provided a large icon via its desktop file, then this will be enough to get KDE's task switcher to use it.

However, if you need to provide a large icon yourself, then you have the following options:

1. Open the `.desktop` file.  Usually it just says `Icon=APP_NAME`

   If this is the case, then you can add a large image to:

   ```
   /usr/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/apps/APP_NAME.png    or at

   /usr/share/pixmaps/APP_NAME.png    (I'm not sure which one wins)
   ```

   You may also generate icons for 16, 32, 48, 64, 128 and 256 size, using

   ```
   sudo convert -background none source_icon.png -scale 16x16 /usr/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps/APP_NAME.png
   ```
2. Alternatively, you can edit the `.desktop` file to point directly to your desired image:

   ```
   Icon=/home/YOUR_USER/Pictures/icons/BEAUTIFUL_ICON_FOR_APP_NAME.png
   ```
3. Or, to avoid using `root` at all, you may create your own `.desktop` file, recommended to place at:

   ```
   /home/YOUR_USER/.local/share/applications/APP_NAME.desktop
   ```

   and then set the Icon file path as in option 2.

After making these changes, rather than restarting the application, I usually go back to the `Special Application Settings / Window Rules`, and change and `Apply` the desktop filename twice, to get KDE to use the new settings.  When testing, `Force` works better than `Apply Initially`.

Comment: answer works, but you need to install `libappindicator3-1` package (`libappindicator-gtk3` for Arch users).